# JSON Array parsing not showing output

Tags: javascript, json

```
[  
   {  
      "MAP_COORDINATES":
          "[[32.732695279933104,74.86289978027344],
            [32.72749665793957,74.85431671142578],
            [32.72143121579454,74.85963821411133],
            [32.72200889472774,74.88521575927734]]"
   }
]
```

how to parse this array. Please help

Comment: post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Changing your code from  `JSON.parse(polyLocation).forEach(function(v) { ...` to `JSON.parse(polyLocation[0].MAP_COORDINATES).forEach(function(v) { ...` should resolve this issue. Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/g82n3mky/).

Comment: i tried this  but control is not going inside the loop. Any suggestion

Comment: Its working for me. Check the Fiddle link in the answer. If you are getting any error in browser console, then please provide details.

Comment: Hi Hector Thanks for your help . Im getting following error on console  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use 

var cordData = JSON.parse(polyLocation);
cordData =cordData['MAP_COORDINATES'];

cordData.forEach(function(v) {

     alert(v[0]);
     path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(v[0],v[1]));
     alert("coords main ="+path[0]);


    })
```

Comment: Hi Piyush control is not going inside the loop. Any suggestion... Thanks

Comment: Check now can u make sure json.parse is not giving error in consol

Comment: Hi Piyush, Thanks for your help . Im getting following error on console  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0. Please help.

Comment: Your json was not stringified properly
"[{"MAP_COORDINATES":[[32.732695279933104,74.86289978027344],[32.72749665793957,74.85431671142578],[32.72143121579454,74.85963821411133],[32.72200889472774,74.88521575927734]]}]"

This should be the correct input

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var a ='[{"MAP_COORDINATES":"[[32.732695279933104,74.86289978027344],[32.72749665793957,74.85431671142578],[32.72143121579454,74.85963821411133],[32.72200889472774,74.88521575927734]]"}]' ;
var b =JSON.parse(a);
var data = JSON.parse(b[0].MAP_COORDINATES);
data.forEach(function(v) {
          console.log(v);
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your json syntax..

```
var app=[ 
   {  
      "MAP_COORDINATES":{
          ["32.732695279933104,74.86289978027344",
            "32.72749665793957,74.85431671142578",
            "32.72143121579454,74.85963821411133",
            "32.72200889472774,74.88521575927734",
   ]}}
];
```

app[0].MAP_COORDINATES[0]

"32.732695279933104,74.86289978027344"